# jQuery: Get double or multiple set rule(s)

Tags: jquery, css, bookmarklet

I want to get the rules of a css file that are double or multiple set
so for example

```
#style1 {width:12px;}

#style2 {width:12px;}

.
.
.

#style1 {width: 12px; height:12px;}
```

then jquery should give me "#style1 is defined double or multiple times"

so how do i process css files in a website directly and css code and detect multiple set rules?

it should work out of the box on every website as bookmarklet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a solution but a place to start. [Here](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Totally_Pwn_CSS_with_Javascript) you can find javascript to find css rules in stylesheets. You can use that to check every rule, and you'll get to where you're going.

Comment: [This](http://tools.pingates.com/) might also be usefull for you if your main goal is not to build a tool but rather to clean your own stylesheets. It has an option to combine rules for duplicated selectors (use with caution)

Comment: seems i have to develope most parts of the wanted tool, but this one helps me a lot Litek